# An API+Worker architecture with a shared DB

Tags: architecture, microservices

We are designing a new service that should do mainly 2 things

**1. Get data from a queue, call an API (lets call it APIx) which returns and ID and save the data from the queue+ID to the DB**

**2. Expose the saved data from step 1 to clients through an API**

There may be thousands of requests per second with multiple different users.

The number of events is hundreds/thousands a day (considerably lower than the amount of requests)

Suggestions which were raised:

1. Naïve all-in-one service that listens to the queue, calls the APIx, saves to DB and also handles the requests.
2. Divide to 2 services - A worker which listens to the queue, calls APIx and saves to DB and an API which gets the data from DB and handles the requests.
3. Divide to 2 services - A worker which listens to the queue, calls APIx but then inserts the message to a different queue, the API listens to the queue and saves to DB, and also handles the requests.

We want to create the isolation so we don't really want suggestion 1.
Main pros of the 3rd suggestion is that only 1 service knows about the DB but the drawbacks is that the API is still "troubled" with work instead of focusing on handling the load from users.

**I've attached a simple diagram for options 2 and 3, is option 2 a good design?**

**Is there a different approach we may be missing?**

[image: Options 2 and 3]

Comment: see [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: @gnat - I am not sure from your link how to turn this question to a "design review " question... as we are considering between alternatives - do you know of a community in which this type of questions is more acceptable?

Comment: @Mithir Regarding the disadvantages to option 3, if your message queue allows it, you can also simply increase the number of APIs that answer user requests and thus scale horizontally, should this be an option. Otherwise option 3 is a well known pattern from CQRS, but of course as gnat already pointed out, it always depends on your use case. I just wanted to mention it in general as food for thought.

Comment: It'd be opinion based when there's not enough details and answers become discussions. E.g. solution 1 is not preferred because you want isolation. Isolation from what? There's also some load numbers in the question, is there performance issue in any of the designs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach in method 3 complicates things a bit since you have to have two queues and processing on both ends of the data pipeline.

From my research on this topic (scaling microservices and event pipeline/queue, I have a list of them [here](https://gist.github.com/nhalstead/3602e3004cd22bb78e95d3739783d5ad)) it's frowned upon to share a database if they are unique systems, supplement that with something like Kafka (or RabbitMQ or Redis...) as it provides a simple queue and event pipeline without "stepping on" other storage backend of other systems (creating a spaghetti of service dependencies).

**A full list of libraries and frameworks that implement Job-based queues/pipelines can be found [here](https://taskqueues.com/#libraries).**

---

I'd prefer method 2 as it has fewer components to fail and easier to manage in one project.

Working on a few projects, I've used the Laravel framework that keeps the code all in one repo. The framework allows you to run a web server and start up a separate queue worker to handle the requests all without duplicating code (Keeping [D.R.Y.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in mind). You can read Laravel specific Job Queuing information [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues).

---

Your specific implementation won't be the same as anyone else's but what I've outlined here is generally what is recommended out in the community.